# Compare start time and end time when user pick the time JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime, input, compare

I have 2 selection input for users to choose their time. And the requirement is that the `startTime < returnTime` (`if startTime >= returnTime`) it will prompt an alert.
I have the following code:

```
var startDate = document.getElementById("startDate");
var returnDate = document.getElementById("returnDate");

if (startTime.value >= returnTime.value ) {
    $("#returnTime")[0].setCustomValidity(
    alert("Return Time cannot be less than Start Time")
);
```

The `startTime > returnTime` still works (means that when I select the `startTime > returnTime`, it will prompt an alert) but when I select the same time (`startTime = returnTime`), it doesn't prompt the alert somehow.

Here is my code for HTML file:

```
<input type="time" id="startTime" name="start_time" value="" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text"">
```

It will display like this in the browser:
[image: Browser screenshot]

I don't know if the format is incorrect or it has some other mechanism behind the scene.

Comment: Perhaps you need to use Start date and start time together to compare it against return date and time? in the example, 8:31 pm has no context, if the same time is in different dates the comparison is no longer equal

Answer (score 0):

May be you should try a library built specifically for dealing with date time like `momentjs` or `dayjs`. They have function like `isAfter()` or `isBefore()` that help compare date time more easier